# JS judges whether a web page is opened by a mobile phone

Tags: javascript, iphone, html

or example, many answers have been searched online.

1. It's all about using navigator. user agent to judge whether the current device is a mobile phone. I tried it one by one, and found that this method can't detect the browser mobile phone simulator such as chrome and firefox, or return to my mobile phone to open, but the result is that I use chrome's analog mobile phone mode, so I have other ability to detect.
2. Window. orientation is also indistinguishable from whether a chrome analog phone is turned on or not.
3. There are also people who can create touch events through document. createEvent ("TouchEvent"), which can not detect whether it is open for analog mobile phones.

4.and so on

Summary: I hope that experienced people can give a solution to detect whether it is a mobile phone. This solution can detect whether it is a mobile phone or a chrome, Firefox analog mobile phone.

Comment: I don’t think there is a foolproof method. There will always be exceptions. What about a phablet, is that a mobile phone? A cellular iPad? When does a phone turn into a tablet into a notebook? It’s generally better to not rely on these kind of detections. What do you need it for?

Comment: A common strategy is to test the screen size. Mobile phones have very small screens.

Comment: I don't know why, I can't directly respond to comments, @ Barmar, check screen size innerWidth, some sizes under widnow. screen, and so on. It's the same on chrome as on mobile phone, so it's impossible to distinguish whether it's mobile phone on or not.